# How can I set two baseURL using axios?

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I am currently working on project that requires calling two api's. But, how do I set 2 `baseURL`.

In my `main.js`file

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://192.168.1.75/api'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://192.168.14.66/api'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use prototype method in `main.js` file as below:

```
const authInstance =  axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.75/api'})
Vue.prototype.$auth = authInstance
```